# Pascal Syntax Error

Tags: pascal

I have the following function in my program:

```
function Getrand(rStart,rEnd:Integer): Integer;
var
diff: Integer;

begin
diff := rEnd - rStart;

Getrand := Random(diff) + rStart;
end;
```

When I try to compile the program, I get this error:

```
Failed when compiling
Line 27: [Error] (27:9): Invalid number of parameters in script
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And this brings back memories from ages past. When last hav a seen some pascal code **X-)**

Comment: @Marcelo this line: `Getrand := Random(diff) + rStart;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps your flavour of Pascal doesn't support the traditional return value syntax. Try `Result := …` instead of `Getrand := …`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
Exit(Random(diff) + rStart)
```

instead. But keep in mind that if you do that it will exit from function after returning the value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write Getrand(Random(diff),rStart); to send variables to function